# Create project from existing project Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have downloaded some source code that contains `src` folders with some `.java` files. I want to try to run the code in netbeans.

This is the structure of the folder :

```
C4.5/src/main/java/myc45/
```

and in these folder include some .java files.

What should I do first?

Comment: And there's no build file (ant `build.xml` or maven `pom.xml`) file?

Comment: no. i want to run code from https://github.com/scottjulian/C4.5

Comment: You can supply additional "sources" for a project from within the project properties

Answer (score 3):

When you create a project in Netbeans, one of the options in the project creation window is create project from existing source.  If you have an existing project, you can also edit the project properties and tell it what the source folders are.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @PaulJAbernathy 's solution:

1. create a new project in Netbeans
2. via the projects windows, create a package myc45 (the package name used in the code you want to import) - you can do so by rightclicking, new Package
3. now, inside the `src` directory of your project directory you'll find a directory called `myc45`. Drop the source files into that directory using whatever file browser you commonly use. You'll see that Netbeans picks up the files almost immediately in the project explorer.
4. you can now use the code.

A bit messy, but there are advantages: if eg you want to transform a bunch of existing code files into a Maven type project, this is probably the easiest way.